# Woocommerce CSS clash with Thrive Themes for Product Listing

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

On this page: https://compucademy.net/recommended-books/

,I got my list items to line up horizontally by adding

```
.woocommerce .products {
    display:flex;
}
```

However, when I added more items, it became apparent that this was not a good solution, as all items are now on one row, regardless of the number of items.

Without the `flex` display property, the items show vertically, which is not the correct behaviour for the `[products]` woocommerce shortcode. They should be horizontally displayed, with 4 items to a row.

I believe the issue may be due to a conflict between woocommerce and bootstrap css, but I'm not certain of that.

Can anyone please help me to get the items to display as intended by woocommerce, by providing some  suitable css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding *flex-wrap* to it:

```
.woocommerce .products {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```